# Java lanterna - Cannot read user input

Tags: java, lanterna

I have problems with reading user input from java lanterna library terminal. Upon key strike I would like the system to print a certain character on the terminal. I use this code:

public class Snake {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Terminal terminal = TerminalFacade.createTerminal(System.in, System.out,       Charset.forName("UTF8"));
    terminal.enterPrivateMode();
    Key key =terminal.readInput();      
    if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.Tab)

    {
        terminal.moveCursor(100, 100);
        terminal.putCharacter('D');

    }

}
```

}

Unfortunately, I only have terminal opened - I cannot do any input. Anybody has an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the given code, it seems that you are only running through your if statement once before the main method is finished executing.

Try implementing a while loop to continuously search for input like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Terminal terminal = TerminalFacade.createTerminal(System.in, System.out, Charset.forName("UTF8"));
    terminal.enterPrivateMode();

    // I would recommend changing "true" to a boolean variable that you can flip with a key press. 
    // For example, the "esc" key to exit the while loop and close the program  
    Key key;
    while(true){
        // Read input
        key = terminal.readInput();

        // Check the input for the "tab" key
        if (key.getKind() == Key.Kind.Tab){
            terminal.moveCursor(100, 100);
            terminal.putCharacter('D');
        }
    }

    terminal.exitPrivateMode();
}
```

Additionally, check out the [Lanterna development guide.](https://code.google.com/p/lanterna/wiki/UsingTerminal)